# How to deploy iOS App to client App Store Connect with App Manager Role

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I've built a small App for a client who doesn't know anything about programming *(installing Xcode is not an option)* - this client has granted me with the **App Manager** Role on App Store Connect

But I can't seem to figure out how to Sign In my Xcode Build to that account which is now linked to my personal account

that team account does not display in Xcode (only my personal one) - I don't have the password to their App Store Account - how do I Sign the App In given that I have **App Manager** Role on their App Store Connect it should display ?

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: You accepted the customers invite? Does the team appear as an option at top right of App Store connect when you’re logged in?

Comment: Yes I accepted customer invite & his name appears in the App Store connect

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s an individual account though is it an issue if i’m part of the team ?

Comment: That’s normal, you can be a member of multiple teams. Does the clients team appear in Xcode Prefs > Accounts ?

Comment: No it doesn’t appear only my personal account : (

Comment: I accepted the request & have access to his account from my App Store Connect though does it not work because he took individual membership instead of company ?

Comment: It doesn’t matter , an individual or company can invite devs to their team. Horrible solution but have you tried logging out / in Xcode prefs ?

Comment: I've just tried Sign out / in & still only my account shows up :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the developer or distribution certificate in your mac keychain. Login in the provisioning/developer portal and create the certificates from there.

You can go through a good article on how to [code sign](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-code-sign-publish-ios-apps/) IOS apps.